# Encoding $ as ASCII

Tags: php, html, get, ascii

In my HTML-file, I give a value via `GET` to a php. The value is the following: `'var1$var2'`.

In my URL, there is shown the following:

```
/phpmethod.php?q=var1%24var2
```

I looked up `$` in the ASCII table and found out that it has the number 24.

I also tried it with adding

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

to the html but it´s the same result.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Yes, the value is being URL encoded. That's not typically a problem. What problem do you have?

Comment: `%24` is what you get when you apply `urlencode('$')`. What specifically is your problem in doing that? How is it the wrong result?

Comment: The php function requires a `$` instead of a `%24`

Comment: Which php function requires it? Can you give an example of you how wanted to use it? Where does it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to transform the value back to the posted value.

Usually, you wont need these - your `$_GET` and `$_POST` will already be decoded, and will contain the `var1$var2` just like the user entered them.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal -- what it should be. `$` is a special character and can have special meanings if included in a URL. So whenever you send a value that contains `$` this character will be escaped (*urlencoded*) to its hexadecimal value, so `var1$var2` will be `var1%24var2`.

When in your target page (phpmethod.php), you write `GET['q']` the `$` character is automatically *urldecoded* and you'll get the original value `var1$var2` so you don't need to worry about anything.

Other characters that are also escaped include space (`%20`), `/`, `:`, `&`, `?`, etc. Also all Unicode characters above `0x7F` will be escaped too.

You should only use `urldecode` function in a situation when you explicitly used `urlencode` on your data; so never urldecode `$_POST` and `$_GET` values; their already decoded and you might corrupt your data by doing that again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just passing var1$var2 and escaping the value when you get it?

I'm no php coder so I wouldn't now if that works, but I guess it should.